# Java | ORM | Hibernate | for a reporting application thoughts

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, reporting

Pardon me if this question is too open-ended or vague. My intention here is just to get your views and not a right/wrong answer here. I'm going to design a java based Reporting Application which mainly enables my end-users to generate adhoc reports by choosing various attributes present in different tables/views, filter them, aggregate them, group them etc. I've been engaged in an interesting conversation with a group of my colleagues here whether to use an ORM or not for the data access and database abstraction. I understand the primary purpose of ORM that it has to completely start making the developers think in terms of objects than it's physical structures (Tables, Columns etc). I personally feel, using an ORM especially for adhoc reporting wouldn't be of much use purely because of dynamic nature and the flexibility in associating multiple tables at runtime and applying various aggregations, group by functions on the fly. I certainly don't think using an ORM and then building a whole bunch of native SQLs is a good and productive idea as it nullifies the use of an ORM. Thoughts?

Comment: JDBC/native SQL is faster for reporting as compared to any ORM like hibernate, JPA etc. Please see the difference here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575762/orm-technologies-vs-jdbc

Comment: How do native queries come into the picture here?  Yes, if you need to write only native queries then using Hibernate would not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Usually such reports join data from multiple sources (entities) as well as add complex filtering and/or aggregation.

SQL based approach is much more flexible and has much better performance.

You can still have ORM mapping SQL to existing entities but from my experience a separate DTO are required much more often than pure entities (I would say 90% reports columns are different). Sometimes more columns sometime less columns, using different tables etc.

So it could be pure SQL and using JDBCTemplate for mapping. Alternatively you can add MyBatis for the queries.

ORM is good to cover `CUD` from `CRUD` (and a simplest cases of R getById and getAll). Complex R (read) should be done out of ORM.

Just my 2 cents.